# blackberry chat implementation

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface, chat

I'm currently developing an chat client for Blackberry. What is the best way to display the chat messages? I'm looking for something that can look similar to the iPhone chat look.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to implement iPhone-esque look and feel, take a look at [Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276) in the BB knowledge base (about 2/3 down). You can go further and add an image to the sides of the chat bubbles if you'll be having multiple people in it.

That KB article is actually a good read to help you learn about custom layouts in general.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [BBM Social Platform SDK 1.0 for BlackBerry Java](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/06/bbm-sdk-for-java/)?